# SQL combination OR operator of result records

Tags: sql, combinations, operator-keyword

My TABLE is like:

```
S_NO A B C
1    1 1 0
2    0 1 0
3    1 1 0
4    1 1 1
```

I want 'OR' of all A,B,C as a result when I give S_NO's as 1,2 and 3,

result should be like

```
A B C
1 1 0
```

Comment: I didn't get what you are asking but for that o/p you need : `select a,b,c from table where s_no=1;`

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same with MAX

```
SELECT MAX(A), MAX(B), MAX(C) FROM MyTable WHERE S_NO IN (1,2)
```

You'll need a CAST if these are bit columns

```
...MAX(CAST(A AS bit))...
```

Comment: if i want only for S_NO 1 and 2

Comment: Yes agree. You need to cast. +1 for you

Comment: @user2185016 what do you mean by you want for S_No 1 and 2?

Comment: @user2185016: please consider accepting this answer with the tick on the left then

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
SELECT max(A), max(B), max(C) from Table1
```